# UICollectionView inside of UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, storyboard

I have a

- UIScrollView

  - Labels
  - Labels
  - UICollectionView

I have disabled the UICollectionViews scrolling functionality, so I only want to scroll with the Scrollview. My problem is that I don't know how I can calculate the UICollectionViews height so I can update my UIScorllView. If it's many elements inside the UICollectionView, it's get clipped.

I have created this little HTML example to show what I'm looking for
http://jsfiddle.net/hDwPH/

```
Dummy code
```

Comment: What did you end up going with as a solution to this problem?

Comment: Hey, how did you get to solve this problem

Comment: You can solve this without scrollview. You can create collectionview and put the other labels in its section header. So labels will scroll with collection view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So my suggestion would be to use a single UIScrollview. Create your own view (we'll call it A) with whatever you are trying to repeat in the Collection view and addSubview A to the UIScrollview over and over for however many times you want.

Another way that just came to mind would be to use entirely a collectionview create two collectionviewcells, one that has your labels and you only display it for the first cell and the other collectionviewcell for all the others

Comment: So my suggestion would be to use a single UIScrollview. Create your own view (we'll call it A) with whatever you are trying to repeat in the Collection view and addSubview A to the UIScrollview over and over for however many times you want.

Comment: I can whip up a sample project tonight for you to see in code what I'm talk about, if you like?

Comment: I think I get the idea how to achive it. I can try it for my own first. Thanks anyway

Comment: No prob, and I have no problem helping out. Let me know, if you run into any probs.

Comment: @BenCoffman I wouldn't mind if you can whip up a sample for me though. It's more like the Instagram Photo Taker implementation. This guy here https://www.livecoding.tv/video/instagram-esque-photo-picker-swift/ did it, but the constraint is really confusing