# How can I get a UICollectionView to fill the width of its containing scroll view with Auto Layout without going off the screen?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uicollectionview, autolayout

My view heirarchy looks something like this:

```
- View
  - Scroll View
    - Collection View
```

I'm using Auto Layout. The problem is that when I specify that the collection view should take the full width of the superview, it ends up actually taking the full width of the elements contained within it. I.e., if there were 1000 elements in this collection view and each element was 10 pixels wide, the collection view would be 10000 pixels. It appears to ignore my constraints.

The VFL I'm using looks a little like this:

#### Scroll View

```
H:|[scroll]|
V:|[scroll]|
```

#### Collection View

```
H:|[collection]|
V:|[collection]|
```

All views are set to not translate autoresizing masks to constraints.

Comment: A UICollectionView is a UIScrollView.  Why are you putting it inside another UIScrollView?

Comment: possible duplicate of [UICollectionView inside of UIScrollView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16224599/uicollectionview-inside-of-uiscrollview)

Comment: My question simplifies the layout a bunch, but the basic premise is that I have multiple collection views (with different layouts and data sources) within this same scrollview. The layout would not be possible within a single collection view.

Comment: The question you linked to is referencing another problem, but good find. I've had a tough time finding questions similar to this one.

Comment: @AaronBrager let me know if you'd like to see sample code

Answer (score 1):

> when I specify that the collection view should take the full width of
>   the superview, it ends up actually taking the full width of the
>   elements contained within it.

The whole point of a scroll view is that it permits the display of views that are larger than the scroll view itself. So it doesn't make sense to constrain the collection to the scroll view -- subviews of a scroll view can be as big as they want to be. If you want to limit the size of the collection view, just set its width to whatever width you prefer.

Comment: So I guess that's just a limitation we have to live with? Scroll view frames can't be sized automatically to clip their content views. Bummer. :-/

Answer (score 0):

The constraints in your post make the collection view fill the scroll view along both axes.  It's not clear why you'd want to do that.  I will assume you actually want something like the App Store, which has multiple horizontally-scrolling collections in a vertically-scrolling scroll view.

Auto layout has special behavior for scroll views.  Go read [Technical Note TN2154: UIScrollView And Autolayout](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2154/_index.html).

So, a constraint between the edge of a scroll view and a descendant of the scroll view affects the scroll view's content size.  A constraint between the edge of a scroll view and a view outside the scroll view affects the scroll view's frame.

You need to pin the collection view's left edge to the left edge of your top-level view (the superview of the scroll view), and the right edge similarly.  You can't do that with a visual format.  You'll need to explicitly create those constraints (or set them up in your xib or storyboard).